# WP navigation menu bugged on tablet and mobile version

Tags: wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming, nav, custom-wordpress-pages

I use wordpress with the Elementor Pro plugin and the Shade Pro theme. I encounter a problem on the menu when it switches to tablet and mobile version, a kind of very blue appears. It does not come from the button because once removed, the problem persists. Do you have any ideas to solve this? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
button.navbar-toggler[data-toggle="navbarToggler"] {
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's works ! I just change #fff to transparent in my case, but it's the same.